# Buscar última data registrada no cpf_cnpj sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma base que preciso que uma das colunas seja a busca da menor data registrada naquele CPF/CNPJ na base.

No exemplo seria criar a coluna `data_anterior`:

> ```
> cpf_cnpj  | aplicado| data_aplic | data_anterior
> -------------------------------------------------    
> 123456789 | sim     | 22/03/2018 | missing    
> 123456789   não     | missing    | 22/03/2018
> ```

Quando a data for a mesma da `data_aplic` não deve aparecer a informação.

Podem me ajudar a programar essa função em `SQL`?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que necessita?  Dúvidas: (1) a qual coluna se refere em "_preciso que uma das colunas_"? (2) sobre "_a busca da menor data registrada_", em qual coluna deve ser pesquisada a _menor data_? (3) sobre "_não deve aparecer a informação_", a linha deve ser suprimida ou a coluna?

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro você usar a estrutura abaixo:

```
SELECT
  cpf_cnpj,
  aplicado,
  data_aplic,
  IS_NULL((SELECT MIN(data_aplic)
   FROM tabela T2 
   WHERE T1.cpf_cnpj = T2.cpf_cnpj
     AND T1.data_aplicada <> T2.data_aplic), 'missing') AS data_anterior
FROM tabela T1
```

`data_anterior` vai ser preenchida através de *subconsulta*, checando a menor data do `cpf_cnpj` consultado; além disso, o ***[ISNULL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)*** é usado pra exibir o texto que você deseja (no caso, "*missing*").